# Proving/ Disproving that a set is compact in $l^2$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How can I prove or disprove that the following set in the real sequence space $l^2$ ( equipped with the norm $||(X_1,X_2,...)||_2 = \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i^2}$ )  , is  compact?

$$ A = ( (X_1,X_2,...) \mid X_i \geq 0 , \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i =1   )$$

Comment: Each standard  unit vector, $e_i$, is in $A$. Does the sequence $(e_i)$ have a convergent subsequence?